# Treat a dotted suffix as keyword in listings

Tags: listings, characters

I'm writing C++ code in latex with *listings*.

I'm trying to get *listings* to recognise the suffix `.t()`  as a keyword (it means matrix transpose in the *Armadillo* C++ library).

I tried to get the `.`, `(` and `)` recognised as letters (as suggested in the *listings* manual and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10913/using-keywords-including-a-dot-in-the-name-with-the-listings-package)) with  `alsoletter={.,(,)}` while adding `.t()` as a keyword, but it didn't work.

I also saw [a solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25257/how-to-use-a-comma-in-lstlisting-keywords) which involved defining the keyword as a comment, which I would rather not do, because I need comments for different purposes.

Below is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{Cppinput}[1][]{
 \lstset{%
   language={C++},
   alsoletter={.,(,)}, % I also tried {.t()}
   morekeywords={mat, .t() , ones},
   morecomment=[l]//,
   basicstyle= \ttfamily,
   keywordstyle= \color{BrickRed},  
   frame=single, 
   #1
 }
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{Cppinput}
using namespace arma; 

mat A;
mat B;
mat C,

A = B + ones<mat>(n,1) + C.t();
// the ".t()" should be highlited as a keyword.
\end{Cppinput}

\end{document}
```

I have a hunch that the solution may involve `alsoother=()`, but I can't undertand its syntax from the manual and it didn't word in my example as `alsoother=(.t())`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `otherkeywords` for your special string; from the `listings` documentation about `otherkeywords`:

> Defines keywords that contain other characters, or start with digits. Each
>   given "keyword" is printed in keyword style, but without changing the "letter",
>   "digit" and "other" status of the characters. This key is designed to define
>   keywords like `=>`, `->`, `-->`, `--`, `::`, and so on.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstnewenvironment{Cppinput}[1][]{
 \lstset{%
   language={C++},
   otherkeywords={.t()},
   morekeywords={mat,ones},
   morecomment=[l]//,
   basicstyle= \ttfamily,
   keywordstyle= \color{BrickRed},  
   frame=single, 
   #1
 }
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{Cppinput}
using namespace arma; 

mat A;
mat B;
mat C,

A = B + ones<mat>(n,1) + C.t();
// the ".t( )" is highlited as a keyword.
\end{Cppinput}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had missed that part on `otherkeywords`.