# lstinline puts space before dot

Tags: listings

I am trying to use `\lstinline` to style filenames in my document, but it puts some random whitespace befor the dot. I presume it has to do with autosettings for punctuation?

Can I deactivate this with listings or is it a generall Latex Thing?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\color{blue}} % just to demo

\begin{document}

    I use the file \lstinline{file.ext}, which is nice.

\end{document}
```

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/10916/134144 could also be useful to solve your issue.

Comment: If you just want to change the textcolor of the file names, `listings` is not really necessary.

Comment: @leandris The color change is just a demo and I know that I could just change it where needet. It indeet woudn't be necesary to use listings, (I could just use \emph or something simular) but I would still like to know why this is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a monospaced font solves the problem, which doesn't aswer the quetion for why, but works.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily}

\begin{document}

    I use the file \lstinline{file.ext}, which is nice.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

using leandriis suggestion to make the dot a letter does remove the space inside the expretion, but creates wird space after. Any Ideas?

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
    basicstyle=\color{blue},
    alsoletter={.}
} % just to demo

\begin{document}

    I use the file \lstinline{file.ext}, which is nice.

\end{document}
```